# SQL Query builder in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

I need to give users the ability to build a simple SQL query against our database.  Our application is written in Delphi.

I am assuming only moderate levels of knowledge by the user, but they need the ability to build a simple select statement to be able to query against a couple of tables.  If I can make this easy for them, that would be most wondrous.

Does anyone know of a tool or a set of components that I can use to help the users build SQL SELECT statements...

Comment: Knowing the database vendor would help us.

Comment: No, the database vendor is not an issue - you could always use ODBC to get lists of tables, fields, SPs etc.

Comment: I agree with Neil...I figured it would be my problem to deal with the connections, etc.  But, for the record, the database is Advantage Database Server.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the DevExpress [ExpressFilter](http://devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/key_advancedfiltering.xml#autolist2) control to allow users to specify SQL where constraints before.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across FastQueryBuilder http://fast-report.com/en/products/visual-query-builder.html
and 
OpenQueryBuilder http://fast-report.com/en/products/free-query-builder.html 
(apparently differing versions of the same tool) at Fast-Report.
It looks like the right idea.  Anyone have any experience with it?

Comment: Yes, it works very well.  The nice thing about this approach is that it also allows you to use direct SQL or tweak what was generated for power users.

Answer (score 1):

I've used SimpleQuery for years and am quite happy with it. (http://devtools.korzh.com/eq/vcl/) It's not completely intuitive, but once you get the hang of it, you can present fields to the user from your database(s) and they can combine any series of them with ANDs and ORs to make very complex queries. You get a separate SQL window to save the resulting code. I make The resulting dataset available for printout with PrintDat! or to save as CSV data from the Woll2Woll Infopower grid that I use for display. I occasionally allow for XLS export too with XLSReadWrite. It's all quite automatic at this point. Just take the SimpleQuery example and mold that to your particular needs. You should be able to have something very usable in a day. There is a trial and an example free query builder standalone program that will give you an idea of the final look.

Answer (score 1):

Try [EMS Advanced Query Builder](http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/tools/querybuilder).

> is a powerful component suite for
>   Borland® Delphi® and C++ Builder®
>   intended for visual building SQL
>   statements for the SELECT, INSERT,
>   UPDATE and DELETE clauses. It allows
>   you to build new queries visually
>   and/or graphically represent the
>   existing queries in your own
>   applications. The suite includes
>   components for working with standard
>   SQL, MS SQL, InterBase/Firebird,
>   MySQL, PostgreSQL and many more
>   dialects. Advanced Query Builder
>   enables users to make up large and
>   complicated SQL queries with unions
>   and subqueries for different servers
>   without any knowledge of the SQL
>   syntax.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sqlmanager.net](http://sqlmanager.net/i/scr/tools/querybuilder/hs2130_Using%20navigation%20bar.gif))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [sqlmanager.net](http://sqlmanager.net/i/scr/tools/querybuilder/hs2170_Setting%20output%20fields.gif))</sub>

Comment: +1 - I've used this with Interbase/Firebird and it's worked quite well. The interface isn't the most intuitive (though I might be a few revisions behind) but it does work and most users can get their heads around it quickly enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most powerful one is [ActiveQueryBuilder](http://www.activequerybuilder.com/product_vcl.html), which now included with Delphi IDE (Since 2007 I think)

[image]
<sub>(source: [activequerybuilder.com](http://www.activequerybuilder.com/scr/screen4.gif))</sub>

Comment: Mohammed in what version of Delphi 2007 and how do you bring it up? Is it working for the ADO (dbGo) components?

Comment: Wodzu, AFAIK D2007 R2 or update 3, it's part for data explorer, so it's only available within the IDE, you can't use it with your applications, http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/handbook_note_16.html

Answer (score 1):

[TMS Query Studio](http://tmssoftware.com/site/qs.asp)? Good value at 75 Euro..

Answer (score 0):

I've written a couple of similar things in Delphi. It's easy enough to allow the user to pick table and column names by querying the metadata and using lists and tree views for display. The difficulty comes when trying to implement things like joins. I've never come up with a good interface for this, and in my experience neither have many of the major data tools players.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this free builder:

GSC Visual Query Builder v.0.7

Visual Query Builder v.1.0

and some other in Torry:
http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=546