# Visual SQL query Builder for Delphi 2010 and Unidac

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2010, unidac

We are seeking a freeware or opensource Visual SQL Builder for Delphi 2010 and Unidac

We currently allow our clients to perform SQL against our application's database using a standard Memo field and peform button. We would like to enhance this functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A quick Google search (https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+query+builder+Delphi) turns up a few dozen hits. Google is a much more appropriate search engine (by design) than StackOverflow. This question is also an exact duplicate of [SQL Query builder in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1894128/62576), which has several suggestions you could examine.

Comment: Neither of which are opensource/freewware and applicable to Delphi 2010 and UNIDAC.

Comment: There are several that are freeware/open source, adding support for D2010 should probably be trivial (you're dealing with SQL statements, after all), and UNIDAC support should be fairly trivial as well since all the query builders I was support standard Delphi data access. SO isn't a search engine, but I did some on your behalf and found about a dozen that look like they're worth evaluating. Just change the Google search string to insert UNIDAC between 'builder' and 'Delphi'.

Comment: I have been around long enough to know how to work the Google Engine....and have done everything you have mentioned. Been there, done that, with all of the examples. If you know of one in particular that comes to mind, let me know and if i haven't already tried it, i will give it a go. Dealing with SQL statements is not the only thing to worry about when making a non D2010 package or library work with Delphi 2010....surely you have been around long enough to know that.....especially with all of the new changes in the Delphi 2010.

Comment: I'm very familiar with the process (having ported my own former commercial product from Delphi 1 through XE2 Win64). The only part that's anywhere near complicated is the Unicode change that happened in D2009, and since you're dealing with SQL generation the chances are very slim that there's a significant difference. There may be some minor changes needed to support UNIDAC specifics. The other major changes would be related to generics and RTTI; neither  should have an impact on code that had no knowledge of those things. :-) But no problem - you want "free, no labor involved". Good luck. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenQueryBuilder](https://github.com/FastReports/OpenQueryBuilder) is the only one I know of. It's not really the best architecture and the license is a bit unclear. The original developer was a Borland employee, I don't recall the name but when I tried to track him down a few years ago to clarify the license he seemed to have been lost in time and space.

Comment: I originally tried to link to a download link at fast-report.com, but for whatever raeason StackOverflow wouldn't let me post that answer. :-( The github page also contains the name of the developer:  Sergey Orlik

Comment: I originally looked at this one myself when I was doing some google searches, but saw right away that it was for Delphi 5/6/7 and that it hadn't been updated since 2003 (History.txt). Since there are not any other opensource or freeware options, i will have to try this one or some other freeware ones from Torry's site....else i will purchase a commercial package. - THANKS!

Comment: It was easy to get it to compile in Delphi 2007. But the architecture ... ahem ... isn't optimal.